# Reading blueprint variable in other blueprint

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

So I wanna read BP_ThirdPersonCharacter variables in my ThirdPersonMap. The thing is that I followed a youtube tutorial and I am completely new to UE5. And I have no clue if I am doing it right.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXK9D.png)

[BP_ThirdPersonCharacter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur9SY.png)

[ThirdPersonmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPF86.png)

I wanna do so that variable from ThirdPersonCharacter is visible and editable in ThirdPersonMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Error you get is "access none", **it is not a problem of exposing the variable but more about initializing it.** Here, you are using level blueprint, so maybe your character **is not loaded before** the level blueprint, so that last one can't access the variable.

I can't really make sense on what you are trying to do from the screenshot, all I can say is that your variable (either just the variable or the whole Character) is not initialized.

But for sure, if you are trying to implement a double jump as the variable name suggest, then quit that Youtube tutorial because it is absolutly not the way of doing it. I could wrote thousand of line of why, so just first thing first : **you never implement gameplay mechanics in Level Blueprint**. Just never.

Answer (score 1):

click the eye icon near the property to make it public

Comment: I did that. It is actually visible that the eye is open not closed.